# Copying array and extracting

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
var val = [
    {
        "color": '#ABCDEF',
        "data": [
            {x: 1396328400000, y: 92, num: "243", den: "10"},
            {x: 1398920400000, y: 97, num: "239", den: "20"},
            {x: 1425189600000, y: 91, num: "158", den: "30"}
        ],
        "name":'X'
    },
    {
        "color": '#FEDCBA',
        "data": [
          {x: 1396328400000, y: 92, num: "134", den: "10"},
          {x: 1425189600000, y: 91, num: "210", den: "10"}
        ],
        "name":'Y'
    },
    {
        "color": '#ABCFED',
        "data": [
          {x: 1396328400000, y: 92, num: "110", den: "10"},
          {x: 1425189600000, y: 91, num: "10", den: "10"}
        ],
        "name":'Z'
    }
];
```

I copied `val` to `temp` using `slice(0)` and used `splice(2,2)` on `temp` to extract, but the values are yanked out of original array as well, what am i missing here ?

```
temp = val.slice(0);
console.log(temp);
tempData.push(temp[0].data.splice(2, 2));
console.log(temp);
console.log(val);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/o9uud7ht/1/)

Comment: what about tempData variable....??

Comment: what you want to do that is not clear

Answer (score 0):

[slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) only makes a shallow copy. If you want to extract from temp[0].data without modifying it, you can copy it directly:

```
tempData.push(temp[0].data.slice(0).splice(2, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

what about tempData variable....?? if it is not the part of your code then you have to use temp instead of temp
`var temp = val.slice(0);`
`console.log(temp);`
`temp.push(temp[0].data.splice(2, 2));`
`console.log(temp);`
`console.log(val);`